# What is the best way to get document scroll percentage in react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll

I would like to know when the user is nearing the bottom of the document so I can fetch the next page of data from the API.

I currently have this snippet which I am using to get scroll position and total document height but something is off as when user is at the bottom of page, it shows 88% scrolled down page.

```
addScrollListener(){
    window.addEventListener('scroll', debounce(() => {// lodash debounce method.
        let supportPageOffset = window.pageXOffset !== undefined;
        let isCSS1Compat = ((document.compatMode || '') === 'CSS1Compat');
        let scroll = {
           x: supportPageOffset ? window.pageXOffset : isCSS1Compat ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft,
           y: supportPageOffset ? window.pageYOffset : isCSS1Compat ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop
        };

        console.log('scroll.y', scroll.y)
        console.log('offsetHeight', document.documentElement.offsetHeight)

        let scrollPercentage = (scroll.y / document.documentElement.offsetHeight) * 100

        console.log('scrollPercentage', scrollPercentage)

        if(scrollPercentage > 88){ 
           this.props.fetchData(`https://www.reddit.com/r/funny/${this.state.filter}.json?after=${this.props.after}`, this.props.posts)
        }
        }, 300));//ms
  }
```

When I the user is at the bottom of the page, the console.log values are as follows:

```
scroll.y 5222
offsetHeight 5921
scrollPercentage 88.1945617294376
```

Any idea what is causing this discrepancy?

Or is there a better way of detecting scroll percentage in react?

Alternatively perhaps there is a better way to trigger the fetch next page call rather than using scroll percentage?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

The working solution -

```
addScrollListener(){
    window.addEventListener('scroll', debounce(() => {// lodash debounce method.
        let supportPageOffset = window.pageXOffset !== undefined;
        let isCSS1Compat = ((document.compatMode || '') === 'CSS1Compat');
        let scroll = {
           x: supportPageOffset ? window.pageXOffset : isCSS1Compat ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft,
           y: supportPageOffset ? window.pageYOffset : isCSS1Compat ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop
        };

        let scrollPercentage = (scroll.y / (document.documentElement.offsetHeight - window.innerHeight)) * 100

        if(scrollPercentage > 90){ 
           this.props.fetchData(`https://www.reddit.com/r/funny/${this.state.filter}.json?after=${this.props.after}`, this.props.posts)
        }
        }, 300));//ms
  }
```

Comment: Have you considered using [`react-inview`](https://github.com/rxaviers/react-inview)?

Comment: If the screen is 600 pixels tall and your document is 3000 pixels tall, the maximum scroll.y is 2400, not 3000.

Comment: No I hadn't. That could work quite nicely though. Just append a class to the last element rendered each time and when that comes into view, fetch next. I quite like that idea

Comment: @ChrisG I think you're getting mixed up between window height and document height. I am using document height so I don't have to worry about the screen size

Comment: @Stretch0 My point is, you *do* have to worry about the screen size. Again: the maximum y offset is `document.height - window.height`. You are asking what is causing the discrepancy, and I told you.

Comment: @Stretch0 That's just an alias. You need `let scrollPercentage = (scroll.y / (document.documentElement.offsetHeight - windoow.height)) * 100`

Comment: @ChrisG ah yes you are correct. I need to take the window height into account. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose you have a screen of X in height and a document of Y in height, Y >= X.

In this case, at position 0, the bottom position of the screen is X and when you scroll to the very bottom position in the document, the bottom position seen in the screen is Y and the top of the scroll position is Y - X.

So, when you calculate the percentage, when you are say, at position 0 <= Z <= Y, you will need to calculate the percentage of Z of (Y - X), since Z will be the top position.

So, instead of calculating the percentage value of your scroll position compared to document size, you will need to calculate its percentage compared to the difference between the document size and the screen size.

Answer (score 1):

```
const [scrollPercentage, setScrollPercentage] = useState(0);

  const handleScroll = () => {
    const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    const fullHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
    const currentPosition = window.scrollY;

    const scrollPercentage = (currentPosition / (fullHeight - windowHeight)) * 100;

    setScrollPercentage(scrollPercentage);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).